# Request Coalescing in Nginx

Tags: nginx, cache

I have an image resize server sitting behind an nginx server.

On a cold cache two clients requesting the same file could trigger two resize jobs.

```
client-01.net GET /resize.do/avatar-1234567890/300x200.png
client-02.net GET /resize.do/avatar-1234567890/300x200.png
```

It would be great if only one of the requests could go through to the backend in this situation (while the other client is set 'on-hold').

In Varnish there seems to be such a feature, called [Request Coalescing](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/handling_misbehaving_servers.html). However that seems to be a Varnish-specific term. Is there something similar for Nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, "cache lock" is what you're looking for?

- http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_lock (if you're using HTTP proxy)
- http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_cache_lock (FastCGI)